# Plain ArrayList Linq c# 2 syntaxes (need a conversion)

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

This question is purely academic for me and a spinoff of a question I answered here.

[Retrieve object from an arraylist with a specific element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469945/retrieve-object-from-an-arraylist-with-a-specific-element-value/19470084#19470084)

This guy is using a plain ArrayList... I Know not the best thing to do ... filled with persons

```
class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public Person(string name, string gender)
        {
            Name = name;
            Gender = gender;
        }
    }

personArrayList = new ArrayList();

personArrayList.Add(new Person("Koen", "Male"));
personArrayList.Add(new Person("Sheafra", "Female"));
```

Now he wants to select all females. I solve this like this

```
var females = from Person P in personArrayList where P.Gender == "Female" select P;
```

Another guy proposes

```
var persons = personArrayList.AsQueryable();
var females = persons.Where(p => p.gender.Equals("Female"));
```

But that does not seem to work because the compiler can never find out the type of p.

Does anyone know what the correct format for my query would be in the second format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Cast<T>` to cast it to a strongly typed enumerable:

```
var females = personArrayList.Cast<Person>()
                             .Where(p => p.gender.Equals("Female"));
```

`Cast<T>` throws exception if you have anything other than `Person` in your arraylist. You can use `OfType<T>` instead of `Cast<T>` to consider only those objects of type `Person`.

On a side note, kindly use an enum for gender, not strings.

```
enum Sex { Male, Female }

class Person
{
    public Sex Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Right, I was just wondering and threw together an example to show my question... of course we should use an enum but since this was a bad example to start with ....

Comment: @user2888973 Yes so bad that you started with an ArrayList :P Dont forget to accept answers which helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `ArrayList` has untyped members, you'll have to cast the members to `Person`:

```
var females = persons.OfType<Person>().Where(p => p.gender.Equals("Female"));
```

Comment: The first does not work. (Compiler error no where for arraylist) The second does work just fine

Comment: @user2888973 strange, I don't know why.  Anyway, thanks, I removed the first since it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Cast `personArrayList` to its element type and you are done.

```
var persons = personArrayList.Cast<Person>();
```